# Problems with libbz2

Tags: c, compression

I can't get libbz2 to work. After 10 000 characters it terminates with end of stream although the input file contains several gigabytes. I just cannot figure out what goes wrong. Thank you for any remarks.

Here is my code:

```
string read_bz2_file(const string& filename) {
string result;
FILE* f;
BZFILE* b;
const int BUFSIZE = 1000;
char buf[BUFSIZE];
int bzerror;

f = fopen(filename.c_str(), "r");

if (!f) {
    /* handle error */
    cerr << "cannot read file " << filename << endl;
    return "";
}


b = BZ2_bzReadOpen(&bzerror, f, 0, 0, NULL, 0);
if (bzerror != BZ_OK) {
    BZ2_bzReadClose(&bzerror, b);
    cerr << "cannot read file " << filename << endl;
    return "";
    /* handle error */
}

bzerror = BZ_OK;
while (bzerror == BZ_OK /* arbitrary other conditions */) {
    BZ2_bzRead(&bzerror, b, buf, BUFSIZE /* size of buf */);
    cout << "bzerror: " << bzerror << endl;
    if (bzerror == BZ_OK) {
            /* do something with buf[0 .. nBuf-1] */
        result.append(buf);
    }
}
if (bzerror != BZ_STREAM_END) {
    BZ2_bzReadClose(&bzerror, b);
    cerr << "error while reading file " << filename << endl;
    return "";
    /* handle error */
} else {
    result.append(buf);
    BZ2_bzReadClose(&bzerror, b);
    return result;
}
return result;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try to open the file in binary mode, adding a "b" to the fopen mode:

```
f = fopen(filename.c_str(), "rb");
```